# Safely removing an item from a Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have an ArrayList which looks something like this:
Index1: Item1
Index2: Item2
Index3: Item3

If I remove an item `(ArrayList.remove(2))`, I get something like this:

```
Index1: Item1
Index2: Item2
Index3: null
```

Iterating through this with a `for-loop` gives me a `null pointer`.
So I use `ArrayList.trimToSize()`, which gives me:

```
Index1: Item1
Index2: Item2
```

Joy. Except that the for `loop` still gives me a `null pointer`. And if I surround it with a `try-catch` and inspect it, it looks like Java has extended my `ArrayList` back to its original size, complete with `null`:

```
Index1: Item1
Index2: Item2
Index3: null
```

What's going on here? Why is my `trimToSize()` being reversed?
I understand that there are (many) other ways to iterate through something, but I'd like to find out what's happening and why.

Comment: How are you removing the item?

Comment: Iterating through an `ArrayList` should not throw a `nullpointer exception`, thats the charm about the `ArrayLists` you don't have to worry about that crap. Are you removing element on index3 or are you setting it to `null`?

Comment: I agree, that's the charm! Supposedly anyway.
I've added some code - I'm definitely using .remove()

Comment: I've found the answer.
In my for-loop I'm potentially adding some items to the list. Apparently this causes Java to freak out a little, as it's iterating through a changing list. Apparently it should also be throwing a ConcurrentModificationException instead of a generic NullPointer, but hey.
I was barking up the wrong tree I suppose, thanks for the help!

Comment: The Javadocs point out that `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown on a best-effort basis. It's not guaranteed to be thrown in every circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, you are removing items with `=null` on the actual Object. And that is **wrong**. `ArrayList` has an its own `remove()` method which you should use. It automatically removes the object and reduces the size of the list.